# Все возможные комбинации по условию

Tags: python-3.x

Вот если нужно перебрать все возможные комбинации. Можно сделать так.

```
import itertools

for i in itertools.product('0123456789', repeat=4):
    print(''.join(i))
```

А вот как добавить условия?

Ну например, что нельзя комбинировать больше двух одинаковых символов.

Пример:

```
0011 можно.
0001 нельзя.
1000 нельзя.
1001 можно.
```

И как сделать, чтобы после определённого символа нельзя ставить некоторые символы.
Пример.:

```
2345 можно.
2347 нельзя. (т. К. После 4 нельзя ставить 7.)
5612 можно.
5601 нельзя. (т. К. После 6 нельзя ставить 0.)
```

Это нужно чтобы сократить все возможные комбинации.
Буду признателен за помощь.
Код или ссылки очень помогут.

Comment: Генерируйте рекурсивно, передавая на следующий уровень множество допустимых элементов

Comment: Почитал по рекурсию, очень интересно, но нечего не понятно(((